# Encoding a String into HTML object in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I try to create an object on the fly but I can not turn this string into a functional HTML object. Can anyone show me the right way to do this? Thanks.

```
var string ="<select class=\"numbers\">\
                 <?php\
                     foreach($data as $key => $value){\
                         if($key == 0){\
                             echo '<option value=\"'.$value.'\" selected=\"selected\">'.$value.'</option>';\
                         }\
                         else{\
                             echo '<option value=\"'.$value.'\">'.$value.'</option>';\
                         }\
                     }\
                 ?>\
             </select>";

element.prepend(string );
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute that php on the client side?

Comment: Is the string generated when the page loads?  If so why insert it with javascript?  Why not directly?  if not then you cannot include php code in the javascript like that since PHP has to run server-side when the page first loads.

Comment: yes I already do the query previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use PHP in Javascript, as it is server-sided code, and JS will never see it. However, with a pure HTML string, you can do `$(string)`, and it will be the root object in that string as a jQuery object.

So in essence your PHP code would be inside a script tag that would generate the Javascript `string` variable:

```
var string ="<select class=\"numbers\">";
<?php
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        if($key == 0){
            echo 'string += "<option value=\"'.$value.'\" selected=\"selected\">'.$value.'</option>";';
        } else{
            echo 'string += "<option value=\"'.$value.'\">'.$value.'</option>";';
        }
    }
?>
string += "</select>";
```

and your followup Javascript would be:

```
var select = $(string);
element.prepend( select );
```

---

This all will work because the rendered HTML script will look something like this to the browser:

```
var string ="<select class=\"numbers\">";
string += "<option value=\"default\" selected=\"selected\">default</option>";
string += "<option value=\"Option 1\">Option 1</option>";
string += "<option value=\"Option 2\">Option 2</option>";
string += "<option value=\"Option 3\">Option 3</option>";
string += "<option value=\"Option 4\">Option 4</option>";
string += "</select>";

var select = $(string);
element.prepend( select );
```

Comment: Sorry, where and how should I put the code? I try put it in JS script but it doesn't work..

Comment: "Your PHP code would be inside a script tag"... can you be more specific to what is confusing?

Comment: Only if `javascript.js` is generated by PHP and (hopefully) served with the proper `Content-Type` header. This method is not recommended, unless you know what you're doing and how you want your server configuration to change. Simple way is to put it in an inline script tag inside the .php file.

Comment: I put script tag inline in .php file with `type="text/javascript"`, but I got this `Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or `';'' in C:\xampplite\htdocs\simple\library.php on line 43` that would be where the first echo.

Comment: You need extra semicolons on the end of those echo statements

Comment: I've try the second example and it works fine but the first one is not working (not showing the select object). The try out shows that anything inside **foreach** loop is not executed properly. Am I missing something? Because I cannot do it in script tag so I do the query in the `body` tag... this is confusing for me

Comment: By "Anything inside foreach loop", do you mean even adding `echo $key . " => " . $value;` does not work inside the **foreach** loop?

Comment: yes that's right. when I striped everything like this `<?php echo 'string += "<option value=\"default\" selected=\"selected\">default</option>";'; ?>` it's ok, but I need to make foreach loop of the query data.

Answer (score 1):

The great thing about PHP is you can basically put it anywhare you want in the script. The problem that I encounter in this code is because I put the **foreach** loop before the **query**. So what I do is simply replacing the query above script tag that containing foreach loop, and it works. This method is new to me and I learn something new today. Great job everyone and thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

```
var string = '<select class="number">';

<?php
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    echo 'string += \'<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>\'';
} ?>

string += '</select>';
```

Comment: Why vote down ? Please explain cause this answer his question.